# Custom annotation processor VS processing annotation via reflection api

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I want to write simple custom validation annotation and can't find proper info on difference between two ways, that i know, of processing them, which are:

- Reflection API
- Custom processor extending `javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor`

Can please someone tell me the difference between these options and which is better for which scenario, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

An annotation processor runs when you compile your code.  At compile time, it can issue warnings, generate new code, or modify existing code.  (Modifying existing code is frowned upon, but some processors such as Lombok do it.)

The reflection API is accessed when your code runs.  Your code can change its behavior depending on the annotations that it reads via the reflection API.

That explains the key differences.  There are too many different scenarios to list them all, but for any given scenario you can determine the pros and cons based on the differences.